# How can I insert the sourceMappingURL inside the generated .css file using sass?

Tags: javascript, npm, sass, source-maps

In order to work with sourcemaps in devtool I need to add the `sourceMappingURL` comment at the end of my generated .css file. I'm using the new API in order to convert my .scss file but I can't quite grasp the [docs](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/js-api/interfaces/Options#sourceMap) on this particular matter:

> Sass doesn't automatically add a sourceMappingURL comment to the generated CSS. It's up to callers to do that, since callers have full knowledge of where the CSS and the source map will exist in relation to one another and how they'll be served to the browser.

How can I output the `/*# sourceMappingURL=main.css.map */` comment inside my generated .css?
Here's my code:

```js
const path = require('path');
const sass = require('sass');

const inputPath = 'src/scss/main.scss';

const sassResult = sass.compile(path.resolve(inputPath), {
    sourceMap: true,
    outputStyle: 'expanded',
});

console.log(sassResult.css);
```